# .loc slow in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has multiple numerical columns (`varnames`) and a tag column (`groups[0]`) that identifies all the different groups of the observations. I want to take the average of each group and subtract it from the corresponding observations:

```
mean                = df[varnames+[groups[0]]].groupby(groups[0]).mean()
df.loc[:,varnames] -= mean.loc[df[groups[0]]].values
```

My code works but it's taking ages. I have analysed the performance and the line that is taking a long time is this one: `mean.loc[df[groups[0]]].values` I thought this was the most straightforward line. Why is it taking so long? Can I optimize this?

Versions:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.11.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-73-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.17.1
```

Comment: How about some sample data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .loc in pandas slows down calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827285/using-loc-in-pandas-slows-down-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

Use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):
`df.groupby([groups[0]])[varnames].transform(lambda z: z - z.mean())`